# Firebase seems to not resolve current user until after views rendered. Any way around this?

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am converting an app that used Parse as the backbone user database to Firebase. Parse always seemed to re-authenticate the user before any views were rendered or controllers executed. I.e. if you open a page in the site (even a deep linked page like www.mysite.com/admin/my_account_details),

```
Parse.User.current()
```

will return the current user - the Parse toolkit has re-authenticated (or cached) the current user's data. So controller code could depend on Parse.User.current() being a valid user object at all times, if the user was logged in, even when the page is opened deep into the site, say, via a bookmark.

Firebase seems not to work this way. In my .run() method I have something to the effect of:

```
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {   
              // do something with current user
          }
       });
```

but this code gets executed AFTER controller code, which depends on the current user's info. In other words,

```
 firebase.auth().currentUser
```

is returning no user, even though after firebase finishes loading, there will be a current user.

Am I correct in this diagnosis? And is there any way to ensure that firebase re-connects the current user before any controller code is executed?

Comment: There isn't a way to guarantee that the user will be set before your code executes (since it may require a round-trip to the Firebase servers to refresh the access token). Instead I usually handle everything related to the user authentication state in response to `onAuthStateChanged()`.

Comment: Thank you Frank for the prompt response. Basically, every page controller in my app makes server calls that require the userid in order to function. Not sure how to capture all of that in my onAuthStateChanged method :). But let me ponder that. I may also just put the userid in local storage, but that's a bit gross.

Comment: Mark did you ever figure it out ? I have the same issue.

Comment: It's been awhile since I had the problem, so not 100% sure what I did then to solve it, but basically: 1) moved as much "login-oriented" processing as possible into onAuthStateChanged() callback, 2) protect that callback for when the "currentUser" isn't defined, which can happen, 3) cached the last user uid (firebaseid) in a localStorage variable, 4) delayed use of currentuser variable until onAuthStateChanged delivered me a logged in user. 

As Frank says, onAuthStateChanged is asynchronous & can take an arbitrary amount of time to complete, so you need to handle that in an asynchronous way

Comment: oh - and - I created a base "sign-in" state that was not dependent on the user. in onAuthStateChanged, wait til the user is set, then use state.go to redirect to the appropriate page/controller. That way, the controller doesn't fire til the user is set.